# Overwriting the AngularJS URL validator

Tags: validation, angularjs

AngularJS accepts this for a valid URL:

```
var URL_REGEXP = /^(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?$/;
```

Django accepts this:

```
regex = re.compile(
    r'^(?:http|ftp)s?://' # http:// or https://
    r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|' #domain...
    r'localhost|' #localhost...
    r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})' # ...or ip
    r'(?::\d+)?' # optional port
    r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE)
```

The main **practical** difference is that AngularJS accepts `http://some-host-without-tld`, while Django only allows `http://localhost` as a valid URL without TLD.

Since it's problematic to overwrite the Django URL Validator, I want to overwrite the AngularJS validator. I attempted that this way, which works:

```
app.overwriteUrlValidator = function(ngModel) {

    // Django RegExp, ported to JS.
    var URL_REGEXP = /^(?:http|ftp)s?:\/\/(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|localhost|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?::\d+)?(?:\/?|[\/?]\S+)$/gi;

    // Same validator as AngularJS's, only with a different RegExp.
    function urlValidator(value) {
        if (ngModel.$isEmpty(value) || URL_REGEXP.test(value)) {
            ngModel.$setValidity('url', true);
            return value;
        } else {
            ngModel.$setValidity('url', false);
            return undefined;
        }
    }

    // This is the part I'm not happy about. I need to use a timeout
    // because my code is executed before Angular adds its URL validator.
    // If I add mine before Angular does, it will not work for ??? reason.
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        ngModel.$formatters.push(urlValidator);
        ngModel.$parsers.push(urlValidator);
    }, 100);
};


/**
 * Keep track of user's interaction with input fields
 */
app.inputDirective = function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if (ngModel && attrs.type === 'url') {
            app.overwriteUrlValidator(ngModel);
        }
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : '?ngModel',
        link    : link
    };
};
app.directive('input', app.inputDirective);
app.directive('textarea', app.inputDirective);
```

I rather don't switch to another validation directive because I'd have to update and check a lot of code.

Does anyone know a solid way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Angular 1.3, it's relatively easy now that you can completely overwrite existing `$validators`:

```
myApp.directive('input', function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        function allowSchemelessUrls() {
            // Match Django's URL validator, which allows schemeless urls.
            var URL_REGEXP = /^((?:http|ftp)s?:\/\/)(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|localhost|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?::\d+)?(?:\/?|[\/?]\S+)$/i;

            // Silently prefixes schemeless URLs with 'http://' when 
            // converting a view value to model value.    
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
                if (!URL_REGEXP.test(value) && URL_REGEXP.test('http://' + value)) {
                    return 'http://' + value;
                } else {
                    return value;
                }
            });

            ngModel.$validators.url = function(value) {
                return ngModel.$isEmpty(value) || URL_REGEXP.test(value);
            };
        }

        if (ngModel && attrs.type === 'url') {
            allowSchemelessUrls();
        }
    }

    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: link
    };
});
```

Comment: hi, I'm using a version of your solution, but have some issues any chance you can help me with this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901914/angularjs-validate-initial-url-value-with-custom-directive

Comment: Works great, but at lest with Angular 1.4, if you use `require : ['?ngModel']`, the ngModel parameter of the link funtion gets populated with an array, failing at  `ngModel.$parsers.unshift`. With `require : '?ngModel'`` it works.

Comment: In Angular 1.4.2, ngModel is an array and I have to use ngModel[0] instead. Not sure the reason behind this, but changing all instances of "ngModel" to "ngModel[0]" (except for the require obviously) works great for me.

Comment: @fragileninja That depends on the require format specified: `require: ['?ngModel']` = parameter usage `ngModel[0]`, whereas `require: '?ngModel'` = parameter usage `ngModel`. The array format for require is for requiring multiple controllers in your directive. I updated my answer because there was indeed a mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the ng-pattern attribute](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Burl%5D) to strengthen the pattern used for validation. (I haven't seen a way to *weaken* the pattern used--perhaps this is a good thing though.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have thought about this, and it is the most Angular-like way of solving this problem, but I chose not to do this because it pollutes the input fields in my templates with huge `ng-pattern` attributes and I have to remember doing this for every URL field. That's why I went for a directive-based solution.

Comment: So stick the pattern on a scope variable. Keep in mind that it needs to be a RegExp object in that case.

Comment: Yes, as suggested by @Jeff you can keep your regex as a constant and use that constant wherever you need.
Something like `<input ..... ng-pattern="urlRegexPattern">`

Answer (score 0):

We can create a Directive to validate URL. In this example also added GUI validation response. Added Bootstrap validation Class.

```
app.directive('validateWebAddress', function () {
    var URL_REGEXP = /^((?:http|ftp)s?:\/\/)(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|localhost|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?::\d+)?(?:\/?|[\/?]\S+)$/i;
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            element.on("keyup", function () {
                var isValidUrl = URL_REGEXP.test(element.val());
                if (isValidUrl && element.hasClass('alert-danger') || element.val() == '') {
                    element.removeClass('alert-danger');
                } else if (isValidUrl == false && !element.hasClass('alert-danger')) {
                    element.addClass('alert-danger');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Use this in your tag. Model is required. So don't forget do define model.

```
<input type="url" validate-web-address ng-model="DummyClass.WebAddress" class="form-control" id="webaddress" placeholder="Web Address" />
```