# Angularjs - Validate initial url value with custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this custom validation directive:

```
/**
 *  Overwrites default url validation using Django's URL validator
 *  Original source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138574/overwriting-the-angularjs-url-validator
 */
angular.module('dmn.vcInputUrl', [])

.directive('vcUrl', function() {

  // Match Django's URL validator, which allows schemeless urls.
  var URL_REGEXP = /^((?:http|ftp)s?:\/\/)(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|localhost|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(?::\d+)?(?:\/?|[\/?]\S+)$/i;

  var validator = function(value) {
    if (!URL_REGEXP.test(value) && URL_REGEXP.test('http://' + value)) {
      return 'http://' + value;
      } else {
        return value;
      }
    }

  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      function allowSchemelessUrls() {


        // Silently prefixes schemeless URLs with 'http://' when converting a view value to model value.    
        ngModel.$parsers.unshift(validator);

        ngModel.$validators.url = function(value) {
          return ngModel.$isEmpty(value) || URL_REGEXP.test(value);
        };
      }
      if (ngModel && attrs.type === 'url') {
        allowSchemelessUrls();
      }
    }
  };
});
```

It works fine when you 'dirty' the input by typing or pasting, but I need it to run this validation, overwriting the default `type="url"` validation when the value is initially set in the ngModel.

I've tried adding `ngModel.$formatters.unshift(validator);` but it results in the 'http://' being added to input, which I need to avoid as user's changes are manually approved and it would be a waste of time to approve the addition of 'http://'.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you use AngularJS >= 1.3 then you should look at the new $validator pipeline: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html#the-validators-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Set ng-model-options on the input type field, for example:

```html
<input type="text"
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default', debounce: {'default': 0} }"</input>
```

This will ensure your validator gets fired "when the value is initially set in the ngModel", as you have stated in the question.

See detailed AngularJs documentaion on ngModelOptions:[enter link description here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

Answer (score -2):

validation of Url :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form name="form">
      URL: <input type="url" ng-model="url.text"  placeholder="Enter Link" name="fb_link"></input>
 <span class="error" ng-show="form.fb_link.$error.url"></span>
</form>
```