# How do i create custom Directive?

Tags: angularjs

I am training validating user enter data into input box. user after entering webpage into input box click need to validate, whether user enter inputis valid or not. input should not contain space.

```
html
---
<input type="text" name="waddress" ng-model="web.url" placeholder="www.example.com" />
```

Comment: the attribute `type="url"` from input does not work for you?

Comment: you can use [ng-pattren](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) directive instead of custom directive [find a sutable pattren here](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex)  to validate [this can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19829459/5621827)

Comment: using ng-pattren we can't achive custom validation. please help me on the custom directive

Comment: type="url" not validating my requirement @Elmer Dantas

Comment: can you help me on that @jitender

Comment: [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scottux/f7MzW/)

Comment: that is not working , I am using boostrap

Comment: tried but is not working please help me@jitender

Comment: https://www.google.com/ab c/test, abc in between whitespace is there but not throw the error ur js fiddle

Comment: please help me on that

Comment: [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27383830/5621827)